# I am trying to push a struct into a Vec in my ink contract but i keep getting rust compiler error

Tags: ink

```rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[ink::contract]
mod crowd_funding {
    use ink::storage::Mapping;
    
    #[derive(scale::Decode, scale::Encode)]
    #[cfg_attr(
        feature = "std",
        derive(scale_info::TypeInfo, ink::storage::traits::StorageLayout)
    )]

    pub struct IndividualFundMe {
        account_id: AccountId,
        go_fund_id: u64,
        name: String,
        reason_for_fund: String,
        amount_needed: Balance,
        amount_gotten: Balance,
        status: bool,
        donators: Vec<AccountId>
    }

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct CrowdFunding {
        go_funds: Mapping<AccountId, IndividualFundMe>,
        all_go_funds: Vec<IndividualFundMe>,
        successfull_go_funds: Vec<IndividualFundMe>,
        go_fund_id: u64
    }

    impl CrowdFunding {
       
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                go_funds: Mapping::new(),
                all_go_funds: Vec::new(),
                successfull_go_funds: Vec::new(),
                go_fund_id: 1
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn create_crowdfund(&mut self, _name: String, _reason_for_fund: String, _amount_needed: Balance)  {
            let new_gofund =  IndividualFundMe {
                account_id: self.env().caller(),
                go_fund_id: self.go_fund_id,
                name: _name.clone(),
                reason_for_fund: _reason_for_fund.clone(),
                amount_needed: _amount_needed,
                amount_gotten: 0,
                status: false,
                donators: Vec::new()
            };
            self.go_funds.insert(self.env().caller(), &new_gofund);
            self.all_go_funds.push(new_gofund);
            self.go_fund_id += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the compiler error

```rs
`IndividualFundMe` doesn't implement `Debug`
the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `IndividualFundMe`
add `#[derive(Debug)]` to `IndividualFundMe` or manually `impl Debug for IndividualFundMe`
the trait `Debug` is implemented for `Vec<T, A>`
```

Comment: Please paste the compile error message.

Comment: use ink::prelude::{string::String, vec::Vec}; add this

Comment: I added this already Ganesh11 but it still complains

Answer (score 5):

You need to import: `use ink::prelude::vec::Vec;` in the contract's module.

You also need to import `use ink::prelude::string::String;` for strings.

These are the preludes that implement necessary traits to be stored.

Comment: Edited just now, you don't actually need to derive `Debug`, just import these preludes.